# CSS visibility toggle, unchecked at page load, mistakenly shows class of d3 SVG by default

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, toggle

I'm using css toggles to toggle visibility of d3.js path objects by class. The toggles work fine, except for the one which I want to be unchecked (with objects hidden) at page load. At page load, the toggle is indeed not checked, but the objects are visible. If I switch the toggle on and then off again, the objects are hidden. How can I have the objects hidden at the initial page load? Thank you.

```
<tr>
    <td><label class="switch">
            <input id="toggle_min" type="checkbox" >
            <div class="slider"></div>
    </label></td>
</tr>
```

```
function ready(error, topo) {
                
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "min")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(topo.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", d3.geoPath()
            .projection(projection)
        )
        .attr("stroke", "grey")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2);
}

var min_Checkbox = document.querySelector('input[id="toggle_min"]');

    min_Checkbox.onchange = function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            d3.selectAll(".min").attr("visibility", "visible");
        } else {
            d3.selectAll(".min").attr("visibility", "hidden");
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the event listener to a function that's not anonymous and call it after decleration:

```
min_Checkbox.onchange = toggleVisibility;

function toggleVisiblity() {
   if (this.checked) {
       d3.selectAll(".min").attr("visibility", "visible");
   } else {
       d3.selectAll(".min").attr("visibility", "hidden");
   }
}

toggleVisibility.call(min_Checkbox);
```

Comment: Replacing everything after the line `var min_Checkbox = document.querySelector('input[id="toggle_min"]');` with your suggestion results in the paths being visible permanently (ie they start visible, and the toggle has no action). Am I missing something?

Comment: @organon just drop the parentheses: `min_Checkbox.onchange = toggleVisibility;`.

Comment: @organon Yeah I made a small mistake, my bad! Should be fixed now (with the fix Gerardo Furtado suggested)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you. Fixing this does indeed make the toggle work again, with the same caveat as with my initial code -- even with the toggle being unchecked at page load, the paths in question are initially visible. If I toggle on and then back off, only then do the paths become hidden.

Comment: @organon the problem now is `this`, which for the first call is just the `window`. Why don't you just hide everything with d3?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I wondered about that, and tried adding an `.attr("visibility", "hidden")` to the d3 -- the result was permanently hidden paths, not triggerable by the toggle. Do you have something else in mind?

Comment: @organon I've added a `.call` method which should solve the window problem. Can you check if this works?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately the initial page load -- with toggle unchecked at load -- still has visible paths. Toggling on and then off again does hide  the paths.

Comment: @organon And what if you try the following: exchange `toggleVisibility.call(min_Checkbox);` for `d3.selectAll(".min").attr("visibility", "hidden");`; If that doesn't work the code probably gets executed too early...

Comment: Your diagnosis makes sense; the result is the same with this latest.

Comment: The followup question is then... how do I prevent the code from getting executed too early? :-)

Comment: @organon put the last line of my code after the code where you build the whole svg / d3 object. That should solve the trick. If that part is the ready function you supplied in your question, put it at the end of that function.

Comment: Moving that line after the ready function does not change how the toggle works. I also looked at a jQuery version (an example with someone else's code), and when I default to unchecked/hidden, it _also_ does the some thing. Visible by default, no matter what. Very frustrating! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Can you say more about what you mean above -- hiding everything with d3? Do you mean it could then be toggled _on_?

Comment: @organon Just put `.attr("visibility", "hidden")` in the `<g>` itself, when you append it.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado When I tried this approach, the paths are stuck on hidden -- the toggle does not make them visible.